# Ruby on rails string search from system command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i'm trying to kill process by pid with system(`kill -9 @pid`)
where `@pid` is `@pid = %x[pidof program firefox]` is there any way to do that in ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.
Try

```
command = "kill -9 #{@pid}"
system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't actually tried it , but you can have a look at it if it helps:

[RAA - sys-proctable](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/sys-proctable/)

Answer (score 0):

Backticks:

```
`kill -9 #{@pid}`
```

Pure Ruby:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-kill